# UIView is always behind UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a `UIViewController` (**not** a `UITableViewController` because I read that a view controller is best for this kind of behaviour) with a *UITableView*. In this view controller I want to add a floating `UIView` and place it above my tableview, to do so I wrote:

```
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // add button
    let fbv = liquidActionButtonInstance.addActionButton() // this is a UIView
    self.view.addSubview(fbv)
    liquidActionButtonInstance.delegate = self

    // delegate
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

However my floating view appears behind my `UITableView`, how can I add it as the first child of `self.view`? I've used

```
self.view.addSubview(fbv)
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(fbv)
```

Among others and none seems to work.

**Edit:**

I added some screenshots of my view's hierarchy.

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Here I put a little more code:
My ViewController without some unrelated code:

```
    public class ActividadesTableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descripcionFiltrosLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var filtrosLabelBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var filtrosLabelTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    private var liquidActionButtonInstance: FloatingActionButton = FloatingActionButton()

    public var viewModel : ActividadesTableViewModeling?

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Agregar action button
        self.view.insertSubview(liquidActionButtonInstance.addActionButton(),aboveSubview: tableView)
        liquidActionButtonInstance.delegate = self

        // set row's height
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        // delegate
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        // load tableview data
        if let viewModel = viewModel {
            viewModel.loadActividades(withFilters: nil)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: FloatingButton

extension ActividadesTableViewController: FloatingActionButtonDelegate {
    public func performSegueFromFloatingActionButton(segueName name: String) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier(name, sender: self)
    }
}

// MARK: TableView

extension ActividadesTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Omitting this code, just mentioning the methods
    }

    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ActividadCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ActividadTableViewCell
        if let viewModel = viewModel {
            cell.viewModel = viewModel.cellModels.value[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.viewModel = nil
        }

        return cell
    }

    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    }
}
```

And this is how I add the button (in a different class):

```
    func addActionButton() -> LiquidFloatingActionButton {
    let createButton: (CGRect, LiquidFloatingActionButtonAnimateStyle) -> LiquidFloatingActionButton = { (frame, style) in
        let floatingActionButton = LiquidFloatingActionButton(frame: frame)
        floatingActionButton.animateStyle = style
        floatingActionButton.dataSource = self
        floatingActionButton.delegate = self
        floatingActionButton.color = ColoresKairos.principal2
        return floatingActionButton
    }

    let cellFactory: (String) -> LiquidFloatingCell = { (iconName) in
        return LiquidFloatingCell(icon: UIImage(named: iconName)!)
    }
    cells.append(cellFactory("iphone-action-button-group"))
    cells.append(cellFactory("iphone-action-button-notepad"))
    cells.append(cellFactory("iphone-action-button-check-box"))

    let floatingFrame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 56 - 16, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 56 - 16, width: 56, height: 56)
    let bottomRightButton = createButton(floatingFrame, .Up)

    //view.addSubview(bottomRightButton)
    //return view

    return bottomRightButton
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's behind your tableView? Are you using the view hierarchy inspector?

Comment: Seems like you're using [this](https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton) framework. You might try copying what they do in `viewDidLoad` [here](https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton/blob/master/Example/LiquidFloatingActionButton/ViewController.swift).

Comment: Yes, I am using the hierarchy inspector and my floating button is always in the view hierarchy, but behind the tableview

Comment: And indeed I'm using the LiquidFloatingActionButton framework, my method .addActionButton() references a method which does the same as in the example, just returning the button (called bottomRightButton) as a view

Comment: How are you adding the table view?

Comment: The tableview comes from an outlet in my storyboard

Comment: Post some screenshots of what you're seeing in your view hierarchy inspector.

Comment: Done, the selected view is the one I want to place above the tableview

Comment: What view hierarchy operations are you doing and where are you doing them? You are not keeping a reference to fbv; you only want to interact with it in code from `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: The only part where I modify the view hierarchy is in the viewDidLoad() method I posted above. I have a reference to liquidActionButtonInstance, so I just add the view generated from it and add it to the view controller.

Comment: Does `liquidActionButtonInstance` set the button generated to a property? Post more of your code? Where are you trying to adjust your subviews' order?

Comment: I don't have a IBOutlet where I put the button if that's what you mean. I simply ask the factory class to give an instance of the button and simply add it to self.view in my ViewController. I don't really have much code there, just the method I put in the question.

Comment: I know what you're doing regarding that. Can you post more code? Like your entire view controller?

Comment: Provided more info about my code. Thanks for bothering to help me out.

Comment: I'm not getting the same result as you. [This](https://gist.github.com/bgayman/692652ce924e28dc57f926e9dba7a816) is what I'm doing and what I get. Perhaps you can spot what I'm doing different.

Comment: The only difference between your gist and my code is that my ViewControlelr is embed in a UINavigationController, but beyond that I checked and the code is exactly the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here, after debugging the view hierarchy was that my tableView wasn't being added directly to the UIViewController's hierarchy, so it was added above everything else, and adding my FloatingButton as a subview of UIViewController always resulted on it being hidden by my tableView.
My tableView is added via storyboard, and as far as I know this is not the expected behaviour, but in my case just adding the following lines:

```
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    self.view.addSubview(liquidActionButtonInstance.addActionButton())
```

Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the view using `addSubview(_:)` AND `bringToFront(_:)`.  You can also try sending the tableView to the back using `sendToBack(_:)`

Comment: I tried using `self.view.addSubview(fbv)` then `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(fbv)` and lastly `self.view.sendSubviewToBack(tableView)` but my button is still on the back of my tableview

Answer (score 0):

In your document outline menu in your storyboard, you can place your floating view below your TableView in view hierarchy. Then, you can always see your floating view placed above your tableview.

It's gonna be like this.

▼ Your ViewController

Top Layout Guide

Bottom Layout Guide

▼View

▶︎ TableView

▶︎ Floating View

Comment: But If I add a UIView in my storyboard to place my new button, how can I interact with the tableview below it? I need to have access to both the cells of the tableview and the actions in the floating button.

Comment: You create an outlet from the button to the viewController, then you can access it just like you created it in code (but storyboard got the button ready for you).  You can still do everything.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that is working along with its screenshot, I suspect that your call `liquidActionButtonInstance.addActionButton()` returns an empty button?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
   private var liquidButton: LiquidFloatingActionButton?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     tableView.delegate = self
     tableView.dataSource = self

     // Setting up the liquid button
     liquidButton = createLiquidButton()
     view.addSubview(liquidButton!)
   }

   func createLiquidButton() -> LiquidFloatingActionButton {
     let frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 56 - 16, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 56 - 16, width: 56, height: 56)

     let button = LiquidFloatingActionButton(frame: frame)
     button.animateStyle = .Up
     button.color = UIColor.redColor()

     return button
  }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  // UITableView Implementation, not included not relevent for the example.
}
```

[image]